# object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have installed django admin and am getting `object() takes no parameters` error. I see the error is at `debug_toolbar panel.py` line 55. Am not sure how to debug it.

I have pasted the traceback.

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/super_admin/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'debug_toolbar',
'django_extensions',
'apps.app1',
'apps.accounts',
'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/home/environments/env1.6.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/home/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
  File "/home/home/environments/env1.6.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/home/environments/env1.6.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
File "/home/home/environments/env1.6.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_context
  159.         return RequestContext(self._request, context, current_app=self._current_app)
  File "/home/home/environments/env1.6.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _request_context__init__
  55.         context = processor(request)`

Exception Type: TypeError at /super_admin/
Exception Value: object() takes no parameters
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT

Here is my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: What is the contents of your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two entries in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting which are middleware, not context processors. They belong in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',`  were not suppposed to be there.